# How to install CUDA 11.2 and cuDNN 8.1 on WSL2 for TensorFLow 2?

Tags: linux, tensorflow, cuda, windows-subsystem-for-linux, nvidia

I am very much struggling to get NVIDIA's CUDA 11.2 and cuDNN 8.1 for TensorFlow 2 on my WSL2 machine.

- I have followed their guide to install the latest CUDA 11.8 version and it works. The guide can be found [here](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/wsl-user-guide/index.html#getting-started-with-cuda-on-wsl) and is the standard guide recommended by NVIDIA.
- Though, TF2 only supports certain CUDA/cuDNN combinations as shown [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/source#gpu)
- Further, I have found the index of previously available WSL2 releases of CUDA and 11.2.0-1 is listed! You can see it for yourself [here](https://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/cuda/repos/wsl-ubuntu/x86_64/)

Can anybody give me the commands to get CUDA 11.2 and cuDNN 8.1 on my WSL2 machine so that I can finally get back to coding in TensorFlow 2? I am thinking about something like this :

```
wget https://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/cuda/repos/wsl-ubuntu/x86_64/cuda-wsl-ubuntu.pin
sudo mv cuda-wsl-ubuntu.pin /etc/apt/preferences.d/cuda-repository-pin-600
wget https://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/cuda/11.8.0/local_installers/cuda-repo-wsl-ubuntu-11-8-local_11.8.0-1_amd64.deb
sudo dpkg -i cuda-repo-wsl-ubuntu-11-8-local_11.8.0-1_amd64.deb
sudo cp /var/cuda-repo-wsl-ubuntu-11-8-local/cuda-*-keyring.gpg /usr/share/keyrings/
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get -y install cuda
```

My specs :

- OS : Windows 10 (WSL2 compatible 22H2 release, the latest one)
- Processor : AMD Ryzen 7 5800H
- RAM : 32GB
- GPU : NVIDIA GeForce RTX 3070 Laptop GPU
- WSL2 Distro : Ubuntu 20.04.5 LTS

Comment: https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/archive/11.2.1/wsl-user-guide/index.html#running-cuda

Answer (score 1):

You could check out Nvidia's [download installer](https://developer.nvidia.com/cuda-11.2.0-download-archive?target_os=Linux&target_arch=x86_64&Distribution=Ubuntu&target_distro=WSLUbuntu&target_version=20&target_type=deblocal) for WSL-Ubuntu from its download archives.

```
wget https://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/cuda/repos/wsl-ubuntu/x86_64/cuda-wsl-ubuntu.pin
sudo mv cuda-wsl-ubuntu.pin /etc/apt/preferences.d/cuda-repository-pin-600
wget https://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/cuda/11.2.0/local_installers/cuda-repo-wsl-ubuntu-11-2-local_11.2.0-1_amd64.deb
sudo dpkg -i cuda-repo-wsl-ubuntu-11-2-local_11.2.0-1_amd64.deb
sudo apt-key add /var/cuda-repo-wsl-ubuntu-11-2-local/7fa2af80.pub
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get -y install cuda
```

Answer (score -1):

Here is how I did it:

Follow the instructions from [NVIDIA's CUDA Toolkit Downloads page](https://developer.nvidia.com/cuda-downloads?target_os=Linux&target_arch=x86_64&Distribution=WSL-Ubuntu&target_version=2.0&target_type=deb_network) to setup their package repository with the versions specifically for WSL2

```bash
> wget https://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/cuda/repos/wsl-ubuntu/x86_64/cuda-keyring_1.1-1_all.deb
> sudo dpkg -i cuda-keyring_1.1-1_all.deb
> sudo apt-get update
```

And now the fun part, since the repo contains all previous CUDA versions too:

```bash
> sudo apt install cuda-toolkit-11-7
```

I hope this helps some fellow traveler ^^

Answer (score -4):

I just read your question please follow.

1. Do you installed compatible Cuda versions with your target GPU device? Example: I use CuDa 11.6 and for the NVIDIA GeForce RTX 3070 Laptop GPU, 5120 compatible since 8.6, read from [CuDA Nvidia GPU developer](https://developer.nvidia.com/cuda-gpus)
2. Install Tensorflow then Tensorflow GPU, if it still does not recover your GPU you need to build it on your machine that is not a complex task but finding one existing on websites is a more convenient way [Test build configuration](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/source_windows)
3. If you try to build it on Linux you need to install a compatibility version of Cuda and CuDNN [Compatibility Matrix](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/source#gpu)
4. Last I read this question multiple of times, you still can download target versions of CuDA archived [CuDA and CuDNN archive link](https://developer.nvidia.com/rdp/cudnn-archive)

That is because they question then screenshot added see TF2.11 and WSL2.0 related to my answers

[image: Sample]

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I do not think you have understood me right. I have WSL2, i.e. the Windows Subsystem for Linux and I specifically need CUDA 11.2 and cuDNN 8.1. I have been successfull in installing CUDA 11.8, but this is the wrong version for TF2. Also, NVIDIA guide and Ubuntu guide tell me to not refer to the normal CUDA and cuDNN / toolkit installations for Linux but to opt for the WSL2 approved ones. What to do?

Comment: Agree with @aladin - This is just wrong and has nothing to do with the question being asked, unfortunately.  Sorry!

Comment: The user making  this answer has a tendency of always misunderstanding the question and answering nonsense, just take a look at his other "answers".

Comment: I also running on Windows 10 think about it before keeps votes minus or create conversation as that.

Comment: If your answer is not useful or relevant to the person who asked the question, you really can't expect people not to vote accordingly. If you do not understand the question, you are welcome to ask questions in the comments. I understand the occasional misunderstandings, but several of your answers just come across as "here's my code, have fun figuring out how it's relevant," and it seems that often it's not.

Comment: I am sure that I understand the question and WSL2 then what is the problem they keep told in many topics answers that all my answers are wrong !? 
They removed of attaches and anything but I am running on Windows 10 without simulation or WSL2 simulation.

Comment: See the question and my answers, TF running on Windows 10 no simulation and WSL 2 and they keep todo votes for many topics told my answers all are wrong.
( I also compiling with Bazels if you see from other question anyway they keep todo )